# You passed :github as an option for gem 'spree_gateway', but it is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

When I try to install spree on a new app I get this error:

You passed :github as an option for gem 'spree_gateway', but it is invalid.

I am using rails 3.2.11 on windows 7 machine.

```
D:\Dropbox\web\rails_projects\testapp>spree install
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] y
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_gateway
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
←[31mYou passed :github as an option for gem 'spree_gateway', but it is invalid.←[0m
```

Comment: Could you post the content of your Gemfile (or at least the corresponding lines of all spree related gems)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*TL;DR: Upgrade to a later version of Bundler.*

You probably have an old version of Bundler. For example, in my testing this version gives me that error:

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.0.21
```

And the version that works on my machine is:

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.2.3
```

I have not looked any closer but, clearly, there was a change to bundler at some point that added in support for that option. There is a version between those two in which it will start to work. This may be the problem that you are seeing.